# boost.process batch script is not able to to run another program

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, process, batch-file

I am invoking a batch script through `cmd.exe /C` with `Boost.process`

```
  boost::process::context context;
  context.stdout_behavior = boost::process::capture_stream();

#ifdef WIN32
  arguments.push_front("/c");
  arguments.push_front(_script);
  boost::process::child external_process = boost::process::launch("cmd.exe", arguments, context);
#else
  boost::process::child external_process = boost::process::launch(_script, arguments, context);      
#endif      
  boost::process::status status_code = external_process.wait();
```

If I directly invoke the batch file even with cmd.exe /C it calls the external executable.

But when the batch script is called through my program it doesn't call the external program at all. 
The external executable generates some file. also prints some texts to stdout. neither I see those texts not I see any files to be generated.

I've even tried to replace the target executable with `notepad.exe` then a message box appears `Application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150004) click on OK to terminate application`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I discovered is `boost::process::context` is not cross platform. I've to use `boost::process::win32_context` on Windows. and may be there was a problem with `silence_stream` or that may be a problem in my side.

```
//I've a list of argv in arguments

#ifdef WIN32
  arguments.pop_front();
  arguments.push_front(_script);
  arguments.push_front("/C");
  arguments.push_front("script.bat");

  boost::process::win32_context win32_context;
  win32_context.stdout_behavior = boost::process::capture_stream();
  win32_context.environment = boost::process::self::get_environment(); 

  boost::process::child external_process = boost::process::win32_launch(std::string("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"), arguments, win32_context);
#else
  boost::process::context context;
  context.stdout_behavior = boost::process::silence_stream();

  boost::process::child external_process = boost::process::launch(_script, arguments, context);
#endif

  boost::process::status status_code = external_process.wait();
```

It was not getting `PATH` so applications were failing to find `dll`. `win32_context.environment = boost::process::self::get_environment()` fixed that issue.